# The error is incorrect username or password even I've entered the correct credentials

Tags: php, mysql, hash, mysqli, salt

I've created my own way of login.php using hash & salt. When I input new admin account, the password and seems to be working fine on my phpmyadmin but when I calling the hash and salt in my login, the "User doesn't exist" seems to be good. The error is always "Incorrect username & password" even I've entered the right crendentials. I've already used this script at my previous login system but I don't know why it's now working now.

Here's my login.php

```
<?php
include_once('config.php');
session_start();
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$username);

$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT password,salt FROM admin WHERE username='$username'");

$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);

if($username == "" && $password =="") {
    echo '<center>';
    echo '<h3>Please Fill in the blank form</h3>';
    echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="goback" >Log In Again</button>';
    echo '</center>';
} else if($numrows!=0) {
    $userData = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC);
    $hash = hash('sha256', $userData['salt'] . hash('sha256', $password));

    if($hash != $userData['password']) {
        echo '<center>';
        echo '<h3>Incorrent username or password</h3>';
        echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="goback" >Log In Again</button>';
        echo '</center>';
    } else {
        header('Location: firstpagesurvey.html');
    }
} else {
    die('
        <center>
        <h3>Username does\'t exists</h3>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="goback" >Log In Again</button>
        </center>
    ');
}
?>
```

Here's the create_admin action

```
<?php
include_once('config.php');
session_start();

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];

$hash = hash('sha256', $password);

function createSalt(){
    $text = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
    return substr($text,0,3);
}

$salt = createSalt();

$password = hash('sha256', $hash.$salt);

$username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($username);

$query = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `admin`(`username`,`password`,`firstname`,`lastname`,`salt`) VALUES('$username','$password','$firstname','$lastname','$salt')");

$mysqli->close();

header('Location: success.php');

?>
```

Comment: Where is the code saving your username and password?

Comment: Why aren't you checking the responses from your calls to `mysqli` for errors?

Comment: Norberh what do you mean? I have login.html.

Comment: Hobo how to check the responses?

Comment: are you using  hash and salt  while registering your user, so that password get save in DB using  hash and salt ?

Comment: A.P yeah I do. I have hash and salt column. in my admin table... :D

Comment: Shane. Why? $userData['password'] is fetching the column on the database? right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in create page make hash( hash(password).salt) but login page make hash( salt.password).

in your create_admin action, you make hashed password

your code is

```
$password = hash('sha256', $hash.$salt); 
/*and*/
$hash is $hash = hash('sha256', $password);
```

this mean in create_page your hashing is hash( hash(password), salt)

but your login.php

your code is

```
$hash = hash('sha256', $userData['salt'] . hash('sha256', $password));
```

this mean in login your hashing is hash( salt, hash(password) )

in short, your hashing order between create_admin and login is wrong.

Comment: What do you mean? so my $hash will be $hash = hash(hash($password).salt)?

Comment: Ah yeah. So to make it function well, I have to change my login hash to this $hash = hash('sha256', $password , $userData['salt']); am I right?

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is when you create your password.

```
$hash = hash('sha256', $password);
```

IS NOT EQUALS

```
$hash = hash('sha256', $userData['salt'] . hash('sha256', $password));
```

Therefore; you need to modify the way how you encrypt the password or modify the way yo are authenticating

Comment: So what do you mean. So I have to modify my $hash = hash('sha256', $password); to what kind of script?

Comment: when you store the password, you need to change `$password = hash('sha256', $hash.$salt); ` to `$password = hash('sha256', $salt . hash('sha256', $password));` File: create_admin Line: 19

Comment: you need to match your algorithm when you create the password and when you check the password. It is simple.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I've figured it out... Thanks! The sequence should be base on the create_acc.php

```
$password = hash('sha256', $salt.$hash);
```

Login.php

```
$hash = hash('sha256', $userData['salt'] . hash('sha256', $password));
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier and much safer, if you would use the built-in password function [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php). Because the salt is included in the resulting hash-value, you could also do without a separate database field for the salt.

```
// Hash a new password for storing in the database.
// The function automatically generates a cryptographically safe salt.
$hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

// Check if the hash of the entered login password, matches the stored hash.
// The salt and the cost factor will be extracted from $existingHashFromDb.
$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($password, $existingHashFromDb);
```

This would not only create a cryptographically safe salt, it would also use a hash function with a cost factor (BCrypt). Double hashing is often offered out of the box by password-cracker tools. The SHA-* algorithm is too fast and therefore can be brute-forced too easily.

Comment: Ahhh okay. By the way, how can I create a safe page that the unlogin user can't view it? Example my "admin_page.php" where the information information stored. How can I create an PHP code that will alert if the unlogin user view the forbidden page?

Comment: @truelogicINC - Usually every page has to test whether the user is logged in or not, e.g. with checking the username in the session `$loggedIn = isset($_SESSION['user'])`. If the user is not yet logged in, you do a redirect to the login page `header('Location: '.'login.php', true, 303); exit;`.

Comment: Thank you sir. Yeah I have to try this codes and suggestions of yours. :D Thank you so much sir. :D Sir is it hard to learn Laravel? I've been an interview a while ago and they planning to move on from code igniter to laravel. I replied, "I'm not to familiar about laravel." But I'll try to study i. For you sir. Is it hard to learn laravel?

Comment: @truelogicINC - I myself don't easily switch to frameworks, but Laravel is the framework i finally settled on. Maybe the hardest part is to set up a new project, but afterwards it is a pleasure to work with, the framework is very readable and therefore easy to understand. I bought a copy of [Code bright](http://daylerees.com/codebright) to get me started, and together with the [Laravel docu](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0) i could solve all problems i had since. Sure, every framework needs some time to learn, but if you already know about another framework, it shouldn't be too difficult.